# Transport multiple video streams using a single RTSP/RTP service connection

Tags: video, video-streaming, rtsp, rtp, live-streaming

I want to build a software solution to use a single RTSP/RTP service connection to switch different live streams. For instances, I can have two separate RTSP inputs (example such as two separate IP cameras) that I use as input to a single program to generate a single RTSP/RTP  output stream. The output signal could use one of the input streams, so from application level, it looks like the end user will see one single RTSP URL address, but we can manually change the signal on the back-end to change which source end-user will eventually see.

Not sure whether I have put my question clearly. Let me put up an example. I have two IP cameras who send RTSP live streams and one monitor. I'm using the monitor to connect a single RTSP URL. So I want to have the application to take the two camera RTSP signals as input, and generate an output RTSP signal. But I can control which camera I want to watch from the application by click a button, etc.

Note that different signals can have different media properties, different video resolutions, different audio sample rates, audio sample formats, etc.

If it's possible, please point me some directions to work on or some materials I can refer to .

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of the library @ https://net7mma.codeplex.com.

Using it you can mix audio and video tracks from various streams as well as archive incoming streams.

The library is written completely in C# and has no dependencies and also contains a complete Rtsp and Rtp stack if you need to host the videos and play them back to clients.

Answer (score -1):

you can add the 2 streams together in your application by just putting them next to eachother then you'll get a securitycam like software. that should solve your poblem or else you should buy a 2nd monitor..

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I also need to send a single stream URL to  external customers, thus the optimal scenario would be for the stream to switch automatically according to settings, rather instead of showing everything. God knows how many other inputs I can have, and I can't ask everyone just to buy more monitors...